# How can I set submenus to pop-up on the right side in Delphi?

Tags: delphi-2009

I'm building applications in Delphi and have problems with sub-menus. It seems that the default position of a submenu is to the left when activated in later Windows versions(i.e w8 and Windows Server 2012). I want them to appear on the right side (by default) The problem cam be solved in the Settings for TabletPC in the control panel in Windows 8. But in Windows Server 2012 there is no such alternative. How could I set it in Windows Server 2012 or better still, how could I do it programmatically in Delphi?

Thanks in anticipation

Peter

Comment: You have no control over that. The menu behavior is controlled by the OS, not the VCL. The OS decides where and how a menu is displayed.

Comment: do you need for MainMenu or PopupMenu?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need for MainMenu or PopupMenu?

```
{ for Popup menu }

procedure TForm1.FormContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
var
    LMousePosition: TPoint;
begin
    LMousePosition := ClientToScreen(MousePos);
    PopupMenu1.Popup(LMousePosition.X - 125, LMousePosition.Y);
end;

{ for Main menu }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
    LMenuItem: TMenuItemInfo;
    LMainMenu: HMENU;
  LBuffer: Array [0..79] of Char;
begin
    LMainMenu := Self.Menu.Handle;

    LMenuItem.cbSize := SizeOf(LMenuItem);
    LMenuItem.fMask := MIIM_TYPE;
  LMenuItem.dwTypeData := LBuffer;
  LMenuItem.cch := SizeOf(LBuffer);

  GetMenuItemInfo(LMainMenu, miMenuItem1.Command, False, LMenuItem);

    LMenuItem.fType := LMenuItem.fType or MFT_RIGHTJUSTIFY;
  SetMenuItemInfo(LMainMenu, miMenuItem1.Command, False, LMenuItem);
end;
```